# Передача параметра по ссылке с++

Tags: c++, функции, ссылки, параметры

Как передать функции параметр по ссылке со значением по умолчанию?

```
void func(int &i)

void func2(set<int> &s)
```

и при этом иметь возможность вызывать эти функции без аргументов, чтобы переменной i присваивалось значение по умолчанию, а для s вызывался конструктор, чтобы использовать множество set в теле функции.

Comment: а как вы представляете передачу по ссылке и значение по умолчанию? Значение по умолчанию - константа, а вы хотите получить возможность изменять её. Или я что-то не так понял? Как вы хотите использовать такую конструкцию?

Comment: int main()
{
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    
    set<string> sub; // подстроки входящей строки
    substr(str, sub);

    int answ = 0;

    for (auto it = sub.begin(); it != sub.end(); it++)
 if (substr(*it) == subseq(*it)) answ++;

    cout << answ;
}

При этом я не хочу передавать sub второй раз в substr, чтобы не изменять, но он там нужен в функции. Можно определить еще один контейнер, потом его значение копировать или нет в исходный, но это некрасиво. А если бы можно было передавать контейнер для изменения или не передавать вовсе, чтобы вызывался конструктор

Comment: Кто мешает вам сделать overload? А там глядишь и по-умолчанию получится.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать аргумент по умолчанию по ссылке, то этот аргумент должен быть не временным объектом и уже где-то быть определенным на момент вызова функции.

Передача аргумента по неконстантной ссылке предполагает, что этот исходный аргумент будет в функции изменен. Вы не можете передавать по неконстантной ссылке временные объекты.

Поэтому, исходя из условий, указанных в вашем вопросе, скорей всего у вас должны быть две перегруженные функции. Одна функция принимает аргумент по `lvalue`-ссылке с конкретно заданным объектом. Вторая функция оибл принимает временный объект по `rvalue`-сслке, оибо вместо него  использует значение по умолчанию.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>

void func( int &i )
{
    ++i;
    std::cout << "Inside func( int & ) i = " << i << std::endl;
}   

void func( int &&i = int() )
{
    ++i;
    std::cout << "Insde func( int && ) i = " << i << std::endl;
}   


int main() 
{
    int i = 0;

    std::cout << "Before func( i ) i = " << i << std::endl;

    func( i );

    std::cout << "After  func( i ) i = " << i << std::endl;

    std::cout << std::endl;

    i = 0;

    std::cout << "Before func() i = " << i << std::endl;

    func();

    std::cout << "After  func() i = " << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль:

```
Before func( i ) i = 0
Inside func( int & ) i = 1
After  func( i ) i = 1

Before func() i = 0
Insde func( int && ) i = 1
After  func() i = 0
```

В этой программе, когда в качестве аргумента передается `lvalue`, то используется первая функция

```
void func( int &i )
{
    ++i;
    std::cout << "Inside func( int & ) i = " << i << std::endl;
}
```

и она меняет в своем теле исходный аргумент.

Когда же аргумент не указывается, или когда указывается `rvalue`, то есть некоторый временный объект, как, например,

```
func(); // используется аргумент по умолчанию int(), который равен 0
```

или

```
func( 10 ); // используется временный объект - целочисленный литерал - 10
```

то используется вторая функция

```
void func( int &&i = int() )
{
    ++i;
    std::cout << "Insde func( int && ) i = " << i << std::endl;
}
```

Если же вы не собираетесь изменять исходный аргумент, то достаточно объявить одну функцию с параметром в виду константной ссылки. Например,

```
void func( const int &i = int() );
```

Comment: (drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwb1k-Yjy6SBUFN0V0RWeEFjTDQ) (drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwb1k-Yjy6SBZWV4bEFqa182cWc) Третья задача с моим решением. Использовал ваш метод. Большое спасибо, красивое решение (у вас, конечно)

Comment: @EveHo Не за что.:)

Answer (score 4):

Ну, первый случай несложен - если вы хотите иметь возможность использовать значение по умолчанию, то используйте `const int&` -

```
void f(const int& i = 5)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Без `const`, как вы понимаете, вам не удастся передать **значение** - ведь что тогда вы собираетесь менять, передавая число? :)

А вот так - можно:

```
int j = 5;

void f(int& i = j)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int q = 4;
    f();
    f(q);
}
```

Соответственно, то же и с `set<int>&` - как вы себе представляете

> для s вызывался конструктор, чтобы использовать множество set в теле функции

Т.е. вы хотите создавать **новый** `set<int>`? Тогда **где** он должен быть создан? Как локальная переменная, как глобальная, как переменная в вызывающей функции?

Так что по умолчанию для ссылки надо указывать имеющийся объект. Другое просто не имеет никакого смысла. В конце концов, ссылка - это просто адрес, ждя которого гарантируется наличие корректного объекта.

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*

Comment: Неплохо было бы вызвать конструктор для локальной set<int> при отсутствии внешнего ссылочного параметра. Но, действительно, с точки зрения ссылки это нелогично. Придется выкручивться по-другому. Спасибо.

Comment: А вы передавайте адрес. Тогда при `nullptr` вы вполне можете создать локальное множество.

Comment: И тогда в функции проверить если параметр nullptr, то создать объект, если параметр отличен, то использовать готовый? Хорошая идея.

Comment: Других не держим :)

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужна именно неконстантная ссылка, то сделать в такой ситуации можно что-то вроде

```
void func2(set<int> &s = some_function())
```

где `some_function` это

```
set<int> &some_function()
{
  ...
}
```

некая функция, которая отвечает за создание этих экземпляров `std::set` в некоем хранилище. Отдельно придется подумать об обеспечении некоей политики их последующего уничтожения, когда они станут ненужными. Как это будет делаться - вопрос отдельный и элегантных решений тут навскидку не видно.

Оптимальное решение может зависеть от конкретной специфики вашей задачи, но сама идея неявного создания (потенциально долгоживущих) объектов через параметр по-умолчанию - сомнительна.

Comment: (https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwb1k-Yjy6SBUFN0V0RWeEFjTDQ)
(https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwb1k-Yjy6SBZWV4bEFqa182cWc)
Третья задача с моим решением. Опора на ответ выше.